# Function that adds struct to an array in the blockchain does not execute when called by another function

Tags: dapp-development, storage, struct, memory

I have a problem that's probably very basic, but I cannot seem to figure the issue out

```
function _CreateBike(uint id, uint generation, string model, string ability, uint8 tier) internal returns(Bike){
    Bike memory bike = Bike(id, generation, 1, tier, model, ability, msg.sender);
    garage.push(bike);
    return bike;
}
```

I have this function above that creates a struct and pushes it to an array, and it works as intended

```
function BuyBike(string model, string ability, uint8 tier) public payable costs(basePrice*tier) {
    Bike memory bike = _CreateBike(garage.length, current_generation, model, ability, tier);
    ownedBikes[msg.sender] = [bike.id];
}
```

however when I run this function which calls on the earlier function, the struct doesn't get added to the array. I assume this has something to do with reference variables and storage in the blockchain vs local memory, but I still cannot figure out how to fix the problem after checking stackoverflow and the solidity docs. Can someone please tell me what's going on?

Comment: Your second function seems to be missing a semicolon. That shouldn't compile. Make sure you're sharing the actual code you're using.

Comment: Sure, I edited the code to make it a bit more general purpose, but I modified my question to include the actual code.

Comment: This code seems to be working fine for me. I made up a `struct Bike { ... }` with the seven fields you were passing and a `Bike[] public garage` and a hardcoded `uint current_generation = 1`, I dropped the `costs` modifier from `BuyBike`, and then I called `BuyBike("model", "ability", 8)` and verified that both `garage[0]` and `garage[1]` had the expected Bike struct in them. (It gets added twice, since it gets added in both `_CreateBike` and `BuyBike`.)

Comment: Looks like you just dropped one of the `push`es. With that modification, it only gets added to `garage` once. (I also dropped the `ownedBikes` line rather than declare another variable.)

Comment: I should add that my testing was in Remix via the JavaScript VM. If you're still seeing issues, perhaps share any other relevant code (like the actual variable declarations and the modifier you're using), tell us how you're deploying and testing the contract, and show us how you're calling `BuyBike` and how you're checking the result.

Comment: That's strange, I'm running the code on remix.ethereum.org, and BuyBike does not work for me as intended. [https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.js](Here's my code), is it working for you there as well? I'm just deploying the contract, buying a bike, and using the getBike method, and I'm getting an error that results when there are no structs added to the array.

Comment: It seems like you tried (and failed) to link to your code. Can you just include it in your question here?

Comment: Also, just a guess, but try removing the `costs` modifier from `BuyBike`. My guess is that this modifier expects a certain value in `msg.value`, and I don't  know how to attach ether to a transaction via Remix.

Comment: That worked! I removed the costs modifier and it went through without any issues. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you so much! I'm new to stack exchange, how can I upvote your comments?

Comment: Hopefully now you see why it's important to share the actual code you're testing. :-) If you simplify, first try to run the simplified code and make sure that you still see the problem. (In this case, your simplified code, once fixed up to compile, wouldn't have exhibited the problem, and that could have led you to find the solution.)

Comment: I added an answer, so you can mark that as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments into an answer:

The issue is the `costs` modifier, which presumably tests `msg.value`. Since there's no way (that I'm aware of) to attach ether to a transaction in Remix when using the JavaScript VM, there's no way to satisfy the `msg.value` requirement, so the function presumably `revert`ed.

Comment: I just tested this and I can send Ether to a contract using the "Value" field below where the Environment is selected in Remix.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to smarx's answer, a way to test in a more production-like enviroment is using a private net, wch could be either ganache or ganache-cli, or a coustom private testnet built with geth. I'm sure there are other optios, but those are the ones i use and know that work.

Friendly disclaimer: some private testnets have their own issues (e.g. ganache doesn't have support for websockets, so event's won't work with web3 1.0, private testnets with geth can have different consensus algorithms than mainnet), so don't use them as a final test before sending code to the main net unless you are sure your code will work the same way.